# Getting a PLS-00103 error while excecting a program to find factorial in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, substitution-variables

So this is my code which I executed in sqllive online ide.

```
declare 
    fac number := 1;    
    n number := &1;  
begin         
    while n > 0 loop   
        fac := n*fac;         
        n := n-1;
    end loop;          

    dbms_output.put_line(fac);   
end;
```

Its giving me a "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:" error

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Live is not SQL*Plus. The ampersand is for SQL*Plus  substitution variables and does not work in SQL Live. You need to edit your anonymous block and supply a value each time before you run it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the need for a pl/sql loop here. You could very well do this with a recursive query:

```
with cte (n, fac) as (
    select ? n, 1 fac from dual
    union all 
    select n - 1, fac * n from cte where n > 1
)
select max(fac) as result from cte
```

The question mark represents the parameter for the query, that is the number whose factorial you want to compute.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1ea46dcc3fcb1b2e108d744a74f8f00)**: when given parameter `4` for example, the query returns:

```
<pre>
| RESULT |
| -----: |
|     24 |
</pre>
```

... which is the result of computation `1 * 2 * 3  * 4`.

You could also phrase this as:

```
with cte (n, fac) as (
    select 4 n, 4 fac from dual
    union all 
    select n - 1, fac * (n - 1) from cte where n > 1
)
select max(fac) as result from cte
```

Comment: Perhaps everything you wrote is correct (I didn't read) - but how is that related to the OP's question? Suppose for example he is practicing writing PL/SQL blocks - how will a SELECT statement, even if correct, help with that? Moreover, it seems the problem is that LiveSQL doesn't understand substitution variables; if he tried the same thing with a SELECT statement, he would run into the same problem. I don't find this answer to be helpful.